# sting up ffmpeg to work in XAMPP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, xampp, ffmpeg-php

I'm trying to figuring out how to install and use ffmpeg on windows 64 with XAMPP.

I have flow [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gU49GiWGGAI&feature=youtu.be) and install the ffmpeg-php librarys and I can see the expansion in the phpinfo().

Now I put my ffmpeg.exe in the site root folder and I run this php script:

```
extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

function convertTo( $input, $output ) 
{
echo $cmd = "ffmpeg -i $input $output";
$outputData = array();
exec( $cmd , $outputData);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($outputData);
}

convertTo( "input.mp4", "output.flv" );
```

and I get this output:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.flv
Array ( )
```

but no encoded file.
My php safe mode is off and the movie file is in the root folder too.

workplace info:

- win7 64bit
- XAMPP 1.7.2
- Apache 2.2
- php 5.3.5

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Enable the error.log, and error reporting. Why did you install the PHP extension, if you use the cmdline tool?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert videos with ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624556/how-to-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: the error reporting is on and no output from error_get_last(), is maybe there is a problem with the directories ? all the files are in the same site root folder.

Answer (score 0):

for windows, use ffmpeg.exe and modify code

```
function convertTo( $input, $output ) 
{
echo $cmd = "c:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg -i $input $output";
$outputData = array();
exec( $cmd , $outputData);
}

convertTo( "d:\www\input.mp4", "d:\www\output.flv" );
```

$outputdata not return anything, so don't expect output.

Comment: i need to use this script on a server so i can use only the root directorie.

all my files are at C:\xampp\htdocs\ffmpeg-test
  -ffmpeg.exe
  -input.mp4
  -script.php

Comment: For above script ffmepeg.exe could be on different location, source and destination could be on different location. Change the path in script as per requirement.

Comment: i moved the files according to the answer and still noting happens.
i downloaded the exe from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and selected the **64-bit Builds (Static)**

Comment: thanks to all, i have played around with the directories and got it working from the root file.