# How to run 'at' command via php system()

Tags: php, unix

For some strange reason this

`echo system("echo 'echo hello > /dev/pts/2' | /usr/bin/at 19:36");`

Refuses to work from my php script, however the command works fine when I just enter it through command line.

I know php has permission to execute some commands. I can run 'ls' from the php script but not the 'at' command. I've tried playing around with file permissions, but so far to no avail :(

**edit**

Permissions for /usr/bin/at are:

`-rwxr-sr-x 1 daemon daemon 42752 Jan 15  2011 at`

I think it's a permissions problem, if I execute the php file from my ssh terminal it works fine, but not from the web.

Comment: What are the permissions of the binary /usr/bin/at ?

Comment: -rwxr-sr-x 1 daemon daemon 42752 Jan 15  2011 at

Comment: I think this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/22953232/1862107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are executing is

```
echo 'hello' > /dev/pts/2 | /usr/bin/at 19:36
```

meaning

```
echo 'hello' > /dev/pts/2
```

and pipe stdout to `/usr/bin/at 19:36` but since you already redirected the echo to `/dev/pts/2`, this will be empty. What you probably meant to do is:

```
echo system("echo 'echo hello > /dev/pts/2' | /usr/bin/at 19:36");
```

You might also want to use `shell_exec` to pass the command through a shell or alternatively `proc_open` which gives you better control over stdin/out/err of the command you are executing. Your example would correspond to (adapted example from php.net docs):

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")  // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);

$process = proc_open('/usr/bin/at', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0], 'echo "hello" > /dev/pts/2');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    $return_value = proc_close($process);
    echo "command returned $return_value. stdout: $stdout, stderr: $stderr\n";
} else {
    echo "Process failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Mmm... I wish it worked, but it still doesn't :(. I think it's a permissions problem, if I execute the php file from my ssh terminal it works fine, but not from the web.

Comment: Your original code will write hello instantly and completely ignore `at`

Comment: Okay, so that's one problem solved :), but at the moment php won't even touch the `at` command :(

Comment: For permission settings, also have a look at the manpage, you can control which users can use `at` in `/etc/at.allow` and `/etc/at.deny`

Comment: www-data was in the /etc/at.deny file. I've removed it from there and added it to the at.allow file, but! it still doesn't work :(

Comment: So the script invoked via CLI works as expected now, but when run via Apache it does not? Make sure it really is `at` failing and not `system()` in general, i.e. try to execute `system("echo "bla" > /tmp/test")` and check if it wrote to `/tmp/test`

Comment: system("echo "bla" > /tmp/test") works perfectly well. So it's not a problem with system(). Let us [continue this discussion in chat (click here)](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11600/discussion-between-emmanuel-and-mensi)

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file check for disable_functions sometimes functions like system are disabled for security reasons.

Comment: The system() function works fine, because I can execute other commands such as the 'ls' command

Comment: Are you running php as SuPHP, FastCGI, etc...?

Comment: FastCGI talking with Nginx web server

Comment: Most likely it has something to do with what user the PHP file is being executed under. Sorry I'm not familiar with Nginx, I would check your log files though there is probably some type of error being recorded.