# php exec command not running?

Tags: php, command-line-arguments, windows-server-2008-r2, pdftk

I have a PHP file Executing a shell command for a tool called PDFTK.

The command works fine when I run it directly from the command line but through the PHP script it self, it does not and doesn't throw an error.

The command i am running is:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$WshShell->Exec("pdftk Template.pdf fill_form 1406822788.fdf output test2.pdf");
```

This takes the .fdf data and puts it into the template pdf and then creates the outout of test2.pdf.

Again, works fine when ran directly through the command line.

Any ideas on what I can try to get this to run?

Comment: Does the script have permissions to run the command?

Comment: Is error reporting on? Check to make sure `exec()` isn't disabled.

Comment: Error reporting is turned on and exec is not disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the return of the method Exec, or try:

```
exec("pdftk Template.pdf fill_form 1406822788.fdf output test2.pdf");
```

Comment: how can I see what exec is returning ?

Comment: With your existing code:  var_dump($WshShell->Exec("pdftk Template.pdf fill_form 1406822788.fdf output test2.pdf"));

Comment: the output when running in command line creates the PDF that is desired. When I run it from php, no error and no pdf

Comment: `object(variant)#2 (0) { } `

Comment: but you should simply try: var_dump(exec("pdftk Template.pdf fill_form 1406822788.fdf output test2.pdf"));

Comment: `Warning: exec(): Unable to fork [C:\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe Template.pdf fill_form 1406822788.fdf output test2.pdf 2>&1] in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\testSubmit.php on line 39 NULL `

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your webserver process user does not have privileges to do so. or

```
Add 2>&1 to the end of your command to redirect errors from stderr to stdout.
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538939/php-exec-will-not-execute-shell-command-when-executed-via-browser) for further clarification

Answer (score -1):

It could be many things, but first thing to do is specify the full path to pdftk binary.  Chances are, the PHP environment (e.g. apache, nginx, etc) does not have the same PATH variables as your user account.

Comment: whats the best way to find the path that should be used?

Comment: Where did you install pdftk?  On command line, run 'which pdftk" or 'whereis pdftk'

Comment: `C:\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe`

Comment: can you up vote this please...? i'm not sure who/what is down voting

Comment: So, you will need to specify full path, and it may require double backslash - like C:\\PDFtk\\bin\\pdftk.exe - try without double backslash first, and if it still doesn't work, then try with double backslash

Comment: Then see LordDef regarding the first steps of getting debug output