# PHP System Call Always Fails

Tags: php, shell, cmd

(Seemingly) no matter what command I try to run with PHP's `system` function, the command always does nothing and then fails with exit code 1. For example,

```
system("echo 'this should definitely work'", $retval);
```

sets `$retval = 1`. So does

```
system("dir", $retval);
```

as well as running an executable that I've written; when I run

```
vfmt -h cat.v
```

from `cmd.exe` the command works and returns with exit code 0, but running

```
system("vfmt -h cat.v", $retval);
```

again sets `$retval = 1`. This `vfmt.exe` file is in the same directory as the `src.php` script that is attempting these `system` calls.

I am nearly at my wit's end trying to figure out what's wrong. What could possibly be causing this issue?

Comment: You should incluclude to the question informations about your environment, such: what server, how do you run php (e.g. server-loaded or php-cgi) and such.. And also some lines from the error-log-file ... Othervise, all answer would only "guessing" - such mine bellow.

Comment: Add 2>&1 to the end of your command to redirect errors from stderr to stdout. This should make it clear what's going wrong. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538939/php-exec-will-not-execute-shell-command-when-executed-via-browser?rq=1

Comment: Try to add path to vfmt.exe, for example: `system("c:\\path_to_exe\\vfmt.exe -h cat.v", $retval);`

Comment: Are you missing a close quote in the original script, or just the question as posed?

Comment: @beroe just the question as posed... sorry, I'll fix it.

Comment: Please give us your `php_info()`. Guessing is soooo boring. You don't have Safe Mode enabled, do you?

Answer (score 2):

You should check your `php.ini` for line like the next:

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
                   ^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and such.

Also check your "safe mode" status,  (php ver. < 5.4) if you have enabled it you can only execute files within the `safe_mode_exec_dir` and so on...

More information [in the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php) and for the execution of commands [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php) and especially for system [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).

Comment: My `php.ini` has `disable_functions=`, and no lines that have anything to do with 'safe mode'. So this is not the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: There are two php.ini sometimes, one for command-line interface and one for apache. /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini or sudo vi /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini. Make sure you are modifying the right one. And of course you need to restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is invariably a shell internal command, not a separate executable. You need something more like

```
system('/bin/sh -c "echo \'foo\'"'); // unix-ish
system('cmd.exe /c echo foo'); // windoze
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but using `cmd.exe -c vfmt -h cat.v` still doesn't work...

Comment: whoops. sorry. it's `/c`.

Comment: ... and neither does `cmd.exe /c vfmt -h cat.v`. Any other ideas?

Comment: vfmt doesn't need the cmd stuff, since it is an executable. try `exec('vfmt ...', $output, $ret); var_dump($output)`.

Comment: That's what I thought. So that leads back to my question of "why doesn't `vfmt -h cat.v` work in a PHP `system` call when it does in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: try the exec() version and look at the output. your system call doesn't return ANY output, so you'd never see any error messages/warnings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59528/discussion-between-feralin-and-marc-b).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely issue is that the "working directory" is not what you expect.

This is hidden as you're checking return value and not screen output; they are different.

Firstly, to monitor: try using `exec` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php as this will help you debug by giving both screen output and return value.

Secondly, to fix:

1 - Specify full paths to both the executable and included files. Assuming this is Windows (you refer to cmd.exe) then run

```
system("c:\PathToPhpFile\vfmt -h c:\PathToCatVFile\cat.v, $retval);
```

or

2 - Change the working directory before calling `system()` or `exec()` by using `chdir()` first.

(Or you can do the cd in a batch file (windows) or concatenate the commands in Linux; but this is less portable.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect the output of the command you're running with system() in order for it to run in the background. Otherwise, PHP will wait for program execution to end before continuing.

```
system('mycommand.exe > output.log', $retval);
system('mycommand.exe 2>&1', $retval);
```

Not sure how you're invoking your script, but perhaps you're running into a PHP [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) (or related) limit. Something to investigate. Also, since you're running on windows, you may need to use absolute paths with your commands when executing system calls as the file you're invoking may not be in any defined PATH.