# php exec() rsync ssh to remote server not working

Tags: php, rsync

I am trying to rsync file from local to remote server.
When i do this on console it works:

> rsync -avzhe ssh /var/www/folder1/file5
>   root@192.168.56.74:/var/www/folder2

but when i do this on my php and run the php script, it doesn't work:

```
$rysncCommand = "rsync -avzhe ssh /var/www/folder1/file5 root@192.168.56.74:/var/www/folder2";

shell_exec($rysncCommand);
```

There is no error shown, so i can't really tell what is the error. Is there something wrong with my php script?

Comment: Your ssh keys should be also on Apache home folder. If not, the rsync will not work. If not check once please.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after this ?

Comment: My ssh keys are in apache home/.ssh folder. and i restarted my apache too. still it's not working with my php script. But it works if i directly execute it from my unix command prompt

Comment: I have edited my answer , please check. I am sure it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to check if you need to be a root or (sudo user) for running rsync.

If yes then exec() command will only work if it is run by same user on `php-cli` (not on browser by Apache user). i.e. Which user you are loggined into shell for run `rsync`.

If it is root or any elavated permission user with sudo permission then, This `rsync` command may not be available to `apache/www-data` user which is working when php script run from browser.

So You try to make a normal user and login through it, Then try `rsync` if you are successful then it may be interesting to see what are other problems can be, But if you getting access/permission denied then obviously you can not run this script at-least on browser.

Besides this One more thing permission may not be directly related to `rsync` command itself but with folder `/etc/test/` which is owned by root user in normal scenario.

For more details you can check this Stack Overflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538939/php-exec-will-not-execute-shell-command-when-executed-via-browser/) .

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I guess you are right, the rsync command may not be available to apache/www-data. I try to trigger my php script from command line (e.g: php myscript.php) and this works. But when i run the php on browser, rsync don't work. Anyways thanks, i will run this with crontab and i think it will work.