# Executing rsync shell command from php file on web browser

Tags: php, shell, rsync

Firstly, we wanna move the changes from one system to another system and for this, we have a shell script in `synchfolders.sh` file as follows

`rsync -av --delete -e 'sshpass -p Wordpress@123 ssh -p 22' root@192.168.2.94:/var/www/html/prosync/wp-content/plugins/ /var/www/html/devsync/wp-content/plugins >> /var/www/html/devsync/wp-content/mysynclog.txt`

and we want to execute this shell script in PHP file by `shell_exec()`
and while executing this PHP file from a browser other than `rsync` command, all are executing but the `rsync` is not executing. We have searched the stuff in SO and we got the link [php exec() rsync ssh to remote server not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772816/php-exec-rsync-ssh-to-remote-server-not-working/30773063#30773063)
as said here, we have tried the PHP file execution from the command line and works perfect but not through the browser. Why, Please let us know where we did a mistake. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Enter the full path of rsync command:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av --delete -e 'sshpass -p Wordpress@123 ssh -p 22' root@192.168.2.94:/var/www/html/prosync/wp-content/plugins/ /var/www/html/devsync/wp-content/plugins >> /var/www/html/devsync/wp-content/mysynclog.txt
```

Comment: We have tried this one to sir, but this one too working by running php script through the command line but not from the browser.Please suggest us the right way to achieve this