# PHP ssh2_exec() not executing iptables command

Tags: php, linux

I wanna execute iptables command on a remote server and  print all the iptables command output using php:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($server_ip, $server_port);

//authenticating username and password
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $server_user, $server_pwd)){
    $conn_error=0;
}else{
    $conn_error=1;
}

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "iptables -L -n --line-number");
stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );
$data = "";
while( $buf = fread($stream,4096) ){
   $data .= $buf."<br>";
}
fclose($stream);
```

server connection and authentication is absolutely fine. but command output 
is blank, basically its not executing commands except basic commands.

Comment: I've tried both ways using path and simply command.

Comment: I'm accessing the server using root user... some basic commands are working fine ... for example ls, pwd etc.

Comment: Got nothing .... same issue

Comment: `iptables` needs to run as root or via `sudo`.

Comment: accessing server by root user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the call to `stream_set_blocking()` which changes the behavior of `fread()`. You can change your code to look something like this:

```
$data = '';
while (!feof($stream)) {
    $data .= fread($stream, 4096);
}

echo "$data\n";
```

Or, more simply:

```
$data = stream_get_contents($stream);
echo "$data\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding sudo to your command as iptables require sudo permissions.

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "sudo iptables -L -n --line-number");
```

Comment: accessing server by root user

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue behind this. 
we've to allow iptables command for apache.

1. Run the command `sudo visudo`. Actually we want to edit the file in `etc/sudoers`.To do that, by using `sudo visudo` in terminal ,it duplicate(temp) `sudoers` file to edit.
2. At the end of the file, add the following ex:-if we want to use command for restart smokeping and mount command for another action,

`www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953232/5979349